# SXA error when creating a site: Unrecognized Guid format

Tags: sxa

I installed a clean Sitecore 8.2 Update 5 instance with SPE 4.7 and SXA 1.5.

I imported a tenant, a site, tenant-specific templates, media etc. from a colleague's environment. I don't think any items are missing, because another colleague used the same package with no issues.

When I try to add a new site to this tenant, I am getting this message:

[image: Unrecognized Guid format]

The error in the SPE logs is not very verbose:

```
12380 17:14:51 INFO  Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
12380 17:14:51 INFO  Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
12380 17:14:51 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession ''.
12380 17:14:51 INFO  The script execution in ScriptSession '' completed in 1 ms.
12380 17:14:51 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|mkb0u2wyy3eyw3pialwk0lwc|45d64bde-0494-4591-904b-bfeee42e1cc2'.
12380 17:14:51 INFO  The script execution in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|mkb0u2wyy3eyw3pialwk0lwc|45d64bde-0494-4591-904b-bfeee42e1cc2' completed in 0 ms.
12380 17:14:51 INFO  Script item set to master:\system\Modules\PowerShell\Script Library\SXA\SXA - Scaffolding\Content Editor\Insert Item\Site in ScriptSession $scriptSession$|mkb0u2wyy3eyw3pialwk0lwc|45d64bde-0494-4591-904b-bfeee42e1cc2.
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:14:51 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|mkb0u2wyy3eyw3pialwk0lwc|45d64bde-0494-4591-904b-bfeee42e1cc2'.
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:14:52 ERROR Unrecognized Guid format. Actual value: 
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:14:52 INFO  The script execution in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|mkb0u2wyy3eyw3pialwk0lwc|45d64bde-0494-4591-904b-bfeee42e1cc2' completed in 776 ms.
```

What could be the reason of this?

**EDIT:** After following Alan's suggestion, I received the following in the output of PowerShell ISE:

```
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Show-NewSiteDialog - Begin
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Show-NewSiteDialog - Process
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-TenantTemplatesRoot - Begin
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-TenantTemplatesRoot - Process
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-TenantItem - Begin
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-TenantItem - Process
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-TenantItem - End
Get-Item : Unrecognized Guid format. Actual value:
At line:16 char:3
+         Get-Item -Path master: -ID $tenantItem.Templates
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Item], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.FormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

Comment: To get more information find the script (`/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Scaffolding/Content Editor/Insert Item/Site`) and remove `try catch` so we can see whole stack.
Additionally add `-Verbose` switch to `New-Site` cmdlet, then we can track it step-by-step

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `Get-TenantItem` cmldet was executed (we've got our tenant) script tries to access `Templates` field.
It looks like it is empty or has some gibberish inside.

Please make sure that those fields are filled

[image]

All of them are heavily used by scaffolding scripts and cannot be empty.
If you are not sure what should be the value of each of them, you can create a new Tenant and see.

To easily export a Tenant use this script:
[image]