# Error when creating site in SXA - Unrecognized Guid format

Tags: sxa, multisite

We are using sitcore 9 update 2 and SXA 1.7.1 when I create site getting below error.
I fixed this error by following this blog at initial level ([SXA error when creating a site: Unrecognized Guid format](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8881/sxa-error-when-creating-a-site-unrecognized-guid-format)) but when I click OK after providing all details in SXA site wizard again getting same after few moments.

[image]

I observed that it is happening only in particular tenant only which we are using for customer. I have another test tenant in same instance where I'm able to create site so it is strange what might cause issue in particular tenant.
Thanks.

```
11576 13:02:08 INFO  Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider5.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
17972 13:02:09 INFO  Script item set to master:\system\Modules\PowerShell\Script Library\SXA\SXA - Scaffolding\Content Editor\Insert Item\Site in ScriptSession $scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|7b6d373d-e6ff-4ff1-9edf-888eae742974.
ManagedPoolThread #1 13:02:09 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|7b6d373d-e6ff-4ff1-9edf-888eae742974'.
ManagedPoolThread #1 13:02:57 ERROR Unrecognized Guid format. Actual value: 
ManagedPoolThread #1 13:02:57 INFO  The script execution in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|7b6d373d-e6ff-4ff1-9edf-888eae742974' completed in 48153 ms.
10612 13:03:36 INFO  Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider5.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
1512 13:03:36 INFO  Script item set to master:\system\Modules\PowerShell\Script Library\SXA\SXA - Scaffolding\Content Editor\Insert Item\Site in ScriptSession $scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|7342fd7f-8226-4b7f-9f32-fdb196e84479.
ManagedPoolThread #9 13:03:36 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|7342fd7f-8226-4b7f-9f32-fdb196e84479'.
ManagedPoolThread #9 13:03:38 ERROR Unrecognized Guid format. Actual value: 
ManagedPoolThread #9 13:03:38 INFO  The script execution in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|7342fd7f-8226-4b7f-9f32-fdb196e84479' completed in 1181 ms.
24012 13:13:46 INFO  Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider5.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
25500 13:13:46 INFO  Script item set to master:\system\Modules\PowerShell\Script Library\SXA\SXA - Scaffolding\Content Editor\Insert Item\Site in ScriptSession $scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|9f732432-c4e4-43e6-8f9e-00939b85ffd6.
ManagedPoolThread #3 13:13:46 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|9f732432-c4e4-43e6-8f9e-00939b85ffd6'.
ManagedPoolThread #3 13:13:49 ERROR Unrecognized Guid format. Actual value: 
ManagedPoolThread #3 13:13:49 INFO  The script execution in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|9f732432-c4e4-43e6-8f9e-00939b85ffd6' completed in 3223 ms.
23508 13:14:17 INFO  Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider5.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
16812 13:14:17 INFO  Script item set to master:\system\Modules\PowerShell\Script Library\SXA\SXA - Scaffolding\Content Editor\Insert Item\Site in ScriptSession $scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|3ba78d60-f6a7-4433-ab39-1be7ebc0ff6e.
ManagedPoolThread #5 13:14:17 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|3ba78d60-f6a7-4433-ab39-1be7ebc0ff6e'.
ManagedPoolThread #5 13:14:19 ERROR Unrecognized Guid format. Actual value: 
ManagedPoolThread #5 13:14:19 INFO  The script execution in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|3ba78d60-f6a7-4433-ab39-1be7ebc0ff6e' completed in 1558 ms.
23392 13:21:58 INFO  Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider5.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
1088 13:21:58 INFO  Script item set to master:\system\Modules\PowerShell\Script Library\SXA\SXA - Scaffolding\Content Editor\Insert Item\Site in ScriptSession $scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|374c7b44-9c03-454b-9c1f-d70c7c0f1df3.
ManagedPoolThread #7 13:21:58 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|374c7b44-9c03-454b-9c1f-d70c7c0f1df3'.
ManagedPoolThread #7 13:22:00 ERROR Unrecognized Guid format. Actual value: 
ManagedPoolThread #7 13:22:00 INFO  The script execution in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|ww13kf3zsz5cxsvzpdskhfr5|374c7b44-9c03-454b-9c1f-d70c7c0f1df3' completed in 1513 ms.
```

Comment: With errors do you see in the spe log files?

Comment: Any non alphanumerical characters in tenants name?

Comment: we used only(a-z characters and first letter is capital). this tenant already have one site. do not know what causing the issue in creating second site. site name is like AbcXyz(capital letter in starting and middle).

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an issue with one (or more) of the templates that exist for that tenant. And with issue, I don't mean you did anything wrong - but the scripts just rely on certain things to be there.

Check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/18856/237. You might have the same issues I had there, but to debug your setup you can run this code in SPE:

```
Import-Function Validate-PowerShell

Test-PowerShell

Try
{
    $ctx = gi .
    Import-Function New-Site
    $model = Show-NewSiteDialog $ctx -Verbose
}
Catch
{
    $ErrorRecord=$Error[0]
    Write-Log -Log Error $ErrorRecord
    Show-Alert "Something went wrong. See SPE logs for more details."
    Close-Window
}
```

This should give you and idea where it is going wrong in your case. Get the last line in the output and search for that in the content tree - it should indicate you in which script it is found. This way you can debug the scripts and determine the issue.