# SXA cannot create site under tenant that already has a site - Unrecognized Guid format error

Tags: sxa

I have an existing tenant with 1 website. I tried to create a new site in the same tenant, but got an SPE error. The logs show me:

> ERROR Unrecognized Guid format. Actual value:

When I create a new tenant, I can create a site in there. And a second one.. No problem.

I did see this Q&A [SXA error when creating a site: Unrecognized Guid format](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/8881/237) but the answer did not solve my issue as I do have those fields filled.

Using Sitecore 9.0.2 and SXA 1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the this script in a SPE console to have more output:

```
Import-Function Validate-PowerShell

Test-PowerShell

Try
{
    $ctx = gi .
    Import-Function New-Site
    $model = Show-NewSiteDialog $ctx -Verbose
}
Catch
{
    $ErrorRecord=$Error[0]
    Write-Log -Log Error $ErrorRecord
    Show-Alert "Something went wrong. See SPE logs for more details."
    Close-Window
}
```

The `Verbose` part is important here to get more information from the Show-NewSiteDialog..

Once I ran this I noticed that the problem was in the `Get-InvokedTenantAction` cmdlet. I changed that one to have some more logs and finally found that the existing templates from the tenant need **Insert options**. And I actually removed those so that field was empty. Changing the script to check the field first fixes that (add the `if` line):

```
if($standardValuesHolder."__Masters") {
  [Sitecore.Data.ID[]]$baseTemplates = $standardValuesHolder."__Masters".Split('|')
  ...
```

I noticed that the `Get-InvokedSiteAction` cmdlet had the same code so I changed it there as well.

But it still didn't work. Apparently all templates (and base templates) for that tenant also need a **Standard Values** item for the script to work. I had one base template that did not. I could have altered the script to check for this as well, but decided to create a standard values item for that one base template.
If you need to alter the script, this line need a check first:

```
$standardValuesHolder = Get-Item -Path master: -ID $template.'___Standard values'
```

This is registered as a bug so it will be fixed in a future version, but if you bump into issues in the meantime this might help.